# Solve SoapClient error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

i try to create orders with CreateOrder method in soap web service:

http://80.72.84.109/MW/services/bilkiservice.asmx?wsdl

with this simple code:

```
    $soap = new SoapClient(MW_SOAP_URL, array(
        "trace" => 1,
        "exceptions" => 1
    ));

    //set headers
    $headerbody = array(
        'Database' => MW_DATABASE,
        'Username' => MW_USERNAME,
        'Password' => MW_PASSWORD
    );
    $ns = 'http://tempuri.org/';
    $header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'AuthenticationHeader', $headerbody);
    $this->soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $orderInfo = array(
        'OrderNumber' => 23344,
        'Email' => 'test@test.com',
        'Delivery' => array(
            'Name' => 'Peter',
            'City' => 'LA',
            'Post' => 1000,
            'Address' => 'Test Street 1',
            'Email' => 'test@test.com',
            'Phone' => '12345'
        ),
        'PaymentType' => 2,
        'Items' => array(
            'OrderItem' => array(
                'Code' => 3479,
                'Quantity' => 1,
                'TotalPrice' => 2.73
            )
        )
    );
    $soap->CreateOrder($orderInfo);
```

But i always get this error:

> ```
> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["CreateOrderResult"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4)
>     { ["ErrorMessage"]=> string(53) "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
>      ["ErrorCode"]=> int(-1) ["Errs"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (0) { } ["OrderID"]=> int(0) } }
> ```

I successfully create new contragent with the other method `CreateContragent`, but `CreateOrder` didn't work.

May be the array data is wrong? But I tried many configurations and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

it is not your fault, your web-services didn't work. that is your CreatingOrder function's result description :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateOrderResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CreateOrderResult>
        <Errs>
          <ErrorItem>
            <ErrorCode>int</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorMessage>string</ErrorMessage>
            <ItemNumber>int</ItemNumber>
          </ErrorItem>
          <ErrorItem>
            <ErrorCode>int</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorMessage>string</ErrorMessage>
            <ItemNumber>int</ItemNumber>
          </ErrorItem>
        </Errs>
        <OrderID>int</OrderID>
      </CreateOrderResult>
    </CreateOrderResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```